# How to get queue size (depth) in Artemis

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

Using a Java client API, how can I get the **queue size** in a remote ActiveMQ **Artemis 2.4.0** broker?

Answer (score 2):

Such feature as stats belongs to the management API. It can be accessed over HTTP (jolokia), JMX or JMX via the messaging API.

There is an example in the official [documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/management.html) for users persistent enough to read it.
I will recite it here for convenience.

```
ClientSession session = ...
ClientRequestor requestor = new ClientRequestor(session, "activemq.management");
ClientMessage message = session.createMessage(false);
ManagementHelper.putAttribute(message, "queue.exampleQueue", "messageCount");
session.start();
ClientMessage reply = requestor.request(m);
int count = (Integer) ManagementHelper.getResult(reply);
System.out.println("There are " + count + " messages in exampleQueue");
```

Comment: I was looking for "queue size" in the docs but in Artemis parlance it should be "message count"... Thanks! By the way, the "messageCount" attribute is a Long, not Integer.

Answer (score 2):

This is the complete runnable example:

```
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQException;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.ClientMessage;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.ClientRequestor;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.ClientSession;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.management.ManagementHelper;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQSession;

String queueName = "MY.QUEUE";

Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();
env.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
env.put("java.naming.provider.url", "tcp://localhost:61616");
InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(env);
ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory)initialContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
Connection connection = cf.createConnection();
Session jmsSession = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
ClientSession session = ((ActiveMQSession)jmsSession).getCoreSession();

ClientRequestor requestor = new ClientRequestor(session, "activemq.management");

session.start();

ClientMessage message = session.createMessage(false);
ManagementHelper.putAttribute(message, "queue." + queueName, "messageCount");

ClientMessage reply = requestor.request(message);

long count = (Long)ManagementHelper.getResult(reply);
System.out.println("There are " + count + " messages in " + queueName);
```